# Laravel - /js/app.js not found 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I installed `Laravel 5.4` in my server `/public_html/laravel/` folder. When I access `example.com/lavarel/public/`, it works.

I copied all my compiled files in my local `public/` folder into the `example.com/lavarel/public/`. Then I add the `<script src="/js/app.js"></script>` into my `welcome.blade.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <!-- UIkit CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.25/css/uikit.min.css" />
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/sass/uikit.css" /> -->

        <!-- jQuery is required -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- UIkit JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app" style="background:#666;height: 100vh;">

            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>

         <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I go to `example.com/lavarel/public/` again, I got `404 error`:

> GET example.com/js/app.js 404 (Not Found)

if I change to `<script src="/laravel/public/js/app.js"></script>`, I will get another `404 error`:

> GET example.com/laravel/public/laravel/public/js/app.js 404 (Not
>   Found)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is laravel allowed to read the files? If not this could also result in an 404 error.

Comment: When you tried with `/laravel/public/....`, are 100% sure you had the initial `/`? I don't see how you would have gotten that error message if you did.

Comment: check your console, from what url it is trying to load the js

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR The OP has included that in the question already.

Comment: I would recommend that you create a new vhost and have Laravel's public folder as the document root for the web server.

Comment: Please try `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: Btw, having a Laravel application directly at the document root, is a bad practice and you should fix it by moving the project directory to an other *no-public-access* location, or change server settings to make `/laravel/public` the document root. It is also a good practice to use `gulp` to manage your packages and all the assets you need to copy to the public directory.

Comment: You might want to try this if you have not solved it yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337405/laravel-8-nginx-app-css-and-app-js-resources-from-public-not-loading-404.

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue. It simply solved by running:
`npm run dev`

Comment: any further explanations? any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Step1: run the below command in your project.
`npm install`

Step2: after successful npm modules installations run the below command.
`npm run dev`

For better understanding visit laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend