# Laravel 8 + nginx - app.css and app.js resources from public/ not loading - 404 not found

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, http-status-code-404, laravel-8

***This might seem like a duplicate question, but it's different.Trust me, I researched the entire stack, laracast, reddit and github for this one***

> I have a `Laravel` app on a `ubuntu VM` with `nginx`. The issue I have
> with my Laravel 8 app is that it's not loading the `app.css` and
> `app.js` files from `public/`. I have ran `npm install & npm run dev/prod` **but I still got the 404 error - not found in the chrome
> console.** So my `app.css and .js` are alive and well in my
> `public/css - /js` folders.The path is also generated correctly for
> the resources/assets.Still not working. I have tried several `server block` configurations, with no succes.
>
> If you have the same issue and have tried `npm install and run dev`,
> using the `asset` helper function to generate the `path`, `<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` and `<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` **and it's still not
> working** check my answer bellow, *it might save you the 1 week I spent
> searching.**emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

The solution, if you have the same configuration as me, is painfully simple.

I installed my Laravel app in the `/home/myUsername/myLaravelAppName` with a symlink for index.php in`/var/www/myLaravelSiteName` - ***/var/www/myLaravelSiteName*** being the default nginx root for serving websites - as you know.

The solution: make a symlink also for each of the /public/css/ and /public/js/ directories to ***/var/www/myLaravelSiteName***, because the `index.php` symlink ***does not also serve css and js folders*** from `/public/`.Apparently this was not so obvious for me.

***Or you could symlink the entire /public/ directory to `/var/wwwmyLaravelSiteName`***.

If this still does not work you might have other issues so keep searching as there are other fixes for those.
One quick but 'dirty' fix would be using the online ***CDN links from bootstrap and adding them in `app.blade.php`***. It will work but it's not recommended.

*Besides, any new custom css/js file you add will have to be loaded, so the proper way of functioning is preferred. Those will have to have symlinks and well if served individually and not with the entire public/ directory.*

PS. do not forget to make the symlink from sites-available to sites-enabled.

My working server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;



    root /var/www/laravel;


    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    index index.php index.html index.htm ;

    server_name laravel www.laravel;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files $uri = 404;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico|html)$ {

        access_log off;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }


    location ~/\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    sendfile off;

}
```